# Reevaluating an expression when Assumptions have changed

Tags: evaluation, assumptions

Is there a way to make this work?

```
THM = TensorDimensions[M];
Assuming[ Element[M, Vectors[n]], 
    THM
]
```

Which gives:

```
TensorDimensions[M]
```

But I would like it to try executing the expression again, and get

```
{n}
```

None of these potential solutions work:

```
 Assuming[ Element[T, Vectors[n]],
      {THM, 
       Simplify[THM],
       Evaluate[THM]}
 ]
```

This works, but is a profoundly ugly kludge:

```
 Assuming[ Element[T, Vectors[n]],
      {THM /. TensorDimensions[x_] :> TensorDimensions[x]}
 ]
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Update`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update) to tell Mathematica that hidden changes have been made that can affect results:

```
THM=TensorDimensions[M];
Assuming[Element[M,Vectors[n]],THM]
```

> TensorDimensions[M]

Using [`Update`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update):

```
Update[M];
Assuming[Element[M,Vectors[n]],THM]
```

> {n}

Comment: Thanks Carl. vv

Comment: One question -- what else does Update[] do?  Does it empty the cache of previous Simplify results?  (And I realized Wolfram may change what it does whenever they want.)